# how to align navigation li items vertical center on navigation bar, without using line height or padding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to align li tags vertically center on a vertical navigation bar, without using line height or padding.

Here is my code.

```
  <header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default nav-main">
    <div class="container-fluid">
<!-- small size devices collapse button -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mobile-menu-expand" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand nav-brand" href="#"><img src="asset/images/main-logo.png" alt=""></a>
      </div> <!--end of navbar-header   -->

<!-- medium size devices menu -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mobile-menu-expand">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">work</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">contact</button></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: What do you mean by vertical align...they are already aligned https://www.codeply.com/go/KahCIAUeju

Answer (score 0):

Just deal with the line-height in css. e.g:

```
    .navbar li
    {
        line-height:20px;
    }
```

Increase or decrease line-height according to your height.